# npm access ls-collaborators is not reading from the custom registry in .npmrc

Tags: npm, gitlab, npm-publish

I have a custom .npmrc file as follows

```
@foo:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
```

```
// This works and it returns the latest dist tag from the registry as configured in .npmrc
npm view --json @foo/my-package dist-tags
```

```
// This fails with a 404
npm access ls-collaborators @foo/my-package

// npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/package/%40foo%2Fmy-package/collaborators?format=cli - Package not found
```

Some more context:
I am trying to publish an npm package to a private package registry on gitlab using the `np` module. These commands seem to be executing as part of one of its steps for user authentication.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `"private": true` is in your package.json file. I was running into a similar problem as you, and adding this fixed it for me.